# Statistical analysis of time to event data

Tags: correlation, survival, autocorrelation, biostatistics

If I have 2 events of interest, lets say $X$ and $Y$.
I would like to know, what is the influence of $Y$ on $X$. It's like a correlation between 2 events, but I'm not sure what is the formal test for this situation. Alternatively, can I use cox regression on $X$ with using binary variable for $Y$ ? Will it answer my question ?

Comment: Usually when dealing with the influence of one variable on another, we'd use "X" for the "cause" (the predictor/ IV) and "Y" for the "effect" (the outcome/ DV). Reversing that may lead to confusion. Certainly an IV can be binary in Cox regression.

Comment: Time series analysis would use cross correlation but may fail for binomial outcomes. Survival analysis would use time-dependent variables. Feasibility for statistical analysis will depend on the number of events.